# Count Sort in C - incomplete sorting

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to write an Count sort Program. My Problem is that it seems to sort the first 4 Numbers and after that he only prints 0. My input comes from an external file.

This is my sorted output:

```
0 1 5 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The following is my code so far:

```
int MAX_LAENGE = 1000;
int MAX_VALUE = 100;
int i, k, j;

void count_sort_calculate_counts(int input_array[], int len, int count_array[]) {
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        count_array[i] = 0;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        count_array[input_array[j]] = count_array[input_array[j]] + 1;
    }
}

void count_sort_write_output_array(int output_array[], int len, int count_array[]) {
    k = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < count_array[j]; i++)
        {
            output_array[k] = j;
            k = k + 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is `len` meant to be the number of elements in `input_array` or the maximum allowed value (i.e. the limit of your count sort). It seems you use it for both, which is wrong. Additionally please note this is not insertion sort (as you say in the question)

Comment: Corrected the Typo in the Question, Thanks! len is the number of elements in the array. I propably need to replace it somewhere, but i don't know where and with what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two of the cycles - the one setting the counts to 0 and the one printing the numbers should not be until len, instead they should be until `MAX_VALUE`.

```
for ( i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++)
{
    count_array[i] = 0;
}
```

Similarly in the function that prints the numbers:

```
for (j = 0; j < MAX_VALUE; j++)
```

Without having more context around how you use this code, this is the only issue I spot.

Comment: Yes that was the problem! Thanks a bunch.